# clean drupal theme for consumer website?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes

I am a drupal newbie and have been looking for drupal themes for my consumer focussed website.
Here is my gripe.
Most free drupal themes look like blog sites
and most premium drupal themes look like corporate websites.
Where do I go looking for a simple clean theme for my consumer website.
I don't need a lot of fluff. Here are the basic requirements,

1. A decent interface for user to register/login
2. Frontpage where I can stick some image or slider
3. Support for full width pages as well as fixed width pages

It would be great if someone can give me pointers on where to look.
Or educate me if I have misunderstood something.
I am open to paying for a theme.

Sorry if my post is on the wrong forum.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Have you come across [Sooperthemes](http://www.sooperthemes.com/)? We've purchased 3 or 4 of their themes before and have been very happy with the features provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when people say a Drupal theme looks like a blog site, I wonder if that's got more to do with the default behavior of the home page (automatically show x latest nodes that are promoted to the front page) than with the theme itself. So it occurs to me that by simply using a very different home page layout, you might get away from the blog look.

One way to lay out the home page (and all other pages) exactly the way you want is to use the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module. You can use Panels to set up individual pages and various page types however you want. It's amazing.

As for specific theme recommendations:

- [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) is very clean and is
  an excellent starter theme
- [Simple Clean](http://drupal.org/project/simpleclean) is
  simple and clean, but it's designed to have 2 fixed-width columns, so
  may not be what you need
- [Talata](http://drupal.org/project/talata) and [web110](http://drupal.org/project/web110) are clean, but
  both are only available for Drupal 7

I hope that helps a bit. If I were you, I would create a Zen subtheme and then use Panels to set up some interesting page layouts.

Comment: +1 for the subtheme suggestion, this really is the best way to go. I takes a bit longer but you end up with a site that looks *exactly* as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) is one of the most popular themes for Drupal. The major advantage is use of the CSS from the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) project. There are also some unique JavaScript & JQuery elements in the theme.